# ¿Hay una forma de hacer doble encabezado en Qtablewidget PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, pyside2

Hola estoy haciendo un reporte utilizando Qtablewidget PyQt5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven la imagen para hacer un doble encabezado utilice varios pushbutton pero me encontré con un problema al querer poner la tabla en gridlayout ya los botones de encabezado no cuadran soy nuevo en PyqT5 Y Quería saber si se puede hacer doble encabezado que me quede con la imagen o otra manera para mejorar el diseño de mi reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Section(object):
    def __init__(self, label='', children=None, isRoot=False):
        self.label = label
        self._children = []
        if children:
            self._children = []
            for child in children:
                child.parent = self
                self._children.append(child)
        self._isRoot = isRoot
        self.parent = None

    def children(self):
        return self._children

    def isRoot(self):
        return self._isRoot

    def iterate(self):
        # an iterator that cycles through *all* items recursively
        if not self._isRoot:
            yield self
        items = []
        for child in self._children:
            items.extend([i for i in child.iterate()])
        for item in items:
           yield item 

    def sectionForColumn(self, column):
        # get the first (child) item for the given column
        if not self._isRoot:
            return self.root().sectionForColumn(column)
        for child in self.iterate():
            if not child._children:
                if child.column() == column:
                    return child

    def root(self):
        if self._isRoot:
            return self
        return self.parent.root()

    def level(self):
        # while levels should start from -1 (root), we're using levels starting
        # from 0 (which is root); this is done for simplicity and performance
        if self._isRoot:
            return 0
        parent = self.parent
        level = 0
        while parent:
            level += 1
            parent = parent.parent
        return level

    def column(self):
        # root column should be -1; see comment on level()
        if self._isRoot:
            return 0
        parentColIndex = self.parent._children.index(self)
        column = self.parent.column()
        for c in self.parent._children[:parentColIndex]:
            column += c.columnCount()
        return column

    def columnCount(self):
        # return the column (child) count for this section
        if not self._children:
            return 1
        columns = 0
        for child in self._children:
            columns += child.columnCount()
        return columns

    def subLevels(self):
        if not self._children:
            return 0
        levels = 0
        for child in self._children:
            levels = max(levels, child.subLevels())
        return 1 + levels
        

class Structure(Section):
    # a "root" class 
    def __init__(self, label='', children=None):
        super().__init__(label, children, isRoot=True)
        
        
class AdvancedHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    _resizing = False
    _resizeToColumnLock = False

    def __init__(self, view, structure=None):
        super().__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, view)
        self.structure = structure or Structure()
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.updateSections)
        self.sectionHandleDoubleClicked.connect(self.emitHandleDoubleClicked)

    def setStructure(self, structure):
        if structure == self.structure:
            return
        self.structure = structure
        self.updateGeometries()

    def updateSections(self, index=0):
        if not self.structure.children():
            return
        section = self.structure.sectionForColumn(index)
        while not section.parent.isRoot():
            section = section.parent
        leftColumn = section.column()
        left = self.sectionPosition(leftColumn)
        width = sum(self.sectionSize(leftColumn + c) for c in range(section.columnCount()))
        self.viewport().update(left - self.offset(), 0, width, self.height())

    def sectionRect(self, section):
        if not self.structure.children():
            return
        column = section.column()
        left = 0
        for c in range(column):
            left += self.sectionSize(c)

        bottom = self.height()
        rowHeight = bottom / self.structure.subLevels()
        if section.parent.isRoot():
            top = 0
        else:
            top = (section.level() - 1) * rowHeight

        width = sum(self.sectionSize(column + c) for c in range(section.columnCount()))

        if section.children():
            height = rowHeight
        else:
            root = section.root()
            rowCount = root.subLevels()
            parent = section.parent
            while parent.parent:
                rowCount -= 1
                parent = parent.parent
            height = rowHeight * rowCount
        return QtCore.QRect(left, top, width, height)

    def paintSubSection(self, painter, section, level, rowHeight):
        sectionRect = self.sectionRect(section).adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1)
        painter.drawRect(sectionRect)

        painter.save()
        font = painter.font()
        selection = self.selectionModel()
        column = section.column()
        sectionColumns = set([column + c for c in range(section.columnCount())])
        selectedColumns = set([i.column() for i in selection.selectedColumns()])
        if ((section.children() and selectedColumns & sectionColumns == sectionColumns) or
            (not section.children() and column in selectedColumns)):
                font.setBold(True)
                painter.setFont(font)

        painter.drawText(sectionRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, section.label)
        painter.restore()

        for child in section.children():
            self.paintSubSection(painter, child, child.level(), rowHeight)

    def sectionHandleAt(self, pos):
        x = pos.x() + self.offset()
        visual = self.visualIndexAt(x)
        if visual < 0:
            return visual

        for section in self.structure.iterate():
            rect = self.sectionRect(section)
            if pos in rect:
                break
        else:
            return -1
        grip = self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_HeaderGripMargin, None, self)
        if x < rect.x() + grip:
            return section.column() - 1
        elif x > rect.x() + rect.width() - grip:
            return section.column() + section.columnCount() - 1
        return -1

        logical = self.logicalIndex(visual)
        position = self.sectionViewportPosition(logical)

        atLeft = x < (position + grip)
        atRight = x > (position + self.sectionSize(logical) - grip)
        if self.orientation() == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and self.isRightToLeft():
            atLeft, atRight = atRight, atLeft

        if atLeft:
            while visual >= 0:
                visual -= 1
                logical = self.logicalIndex(visual)
                if not self.isSectionHidden(logical):
                    break
            else:
                logical = -1
        elif not atRight:
            logical = -1
        return logical

    def emitHandleDoubleClicked(self, index):
        if self._resizeToColumnLock:
            # avoid recursion 
            return
        pos = self.viewport().mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        handle = self.sectionHandleAt(pos)
        if handle != index:
            return
        self._resizeToColumnLock = True
        for section in self.structure.iterate():
            if index in range(section.column(), section.column() + section.columnCount()):
                rect = self.sectionRect(section)
                if rect.y() <= pos.y() <= rect.y() + rect.height():
                    sectCol = section.column()
                    for col in range(sectCol, sectCol + section.columnCount()):
                        if col == index:
                            continue
                        self.sectionHandleDoubleClicked.emit(col)
                    break
        self._resizeToColumnLock = False

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        hint.setHeight(hint.height() * self.structure.subLevels())
        return hint

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        handle = self.sectionHandleAt(event.pos())
        if handle >= 0:
            self._resizing = True
        else:
            # if the clicked section has children, select all of its columns
            cols = []
            for section in self.structure.iterate():
                sectionRect = self.sectionRect(section)
                if event.pos() in sectionRect:
                    firstColumn = section.column()
                    columnCount = section.columnCount()
                    for column in range(firstColumn, firstColumn + columnCount):
                        cols.append(column)
                    break
            if cols:                                    
                self.sectionPressed.emit(cols[0])         
                for col in cols[1:]:
                    self.sectionEntered.emit(col)     

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        handle = self.sectionHandleAt(event.pos())
        if not event.buttons():
            if handle < 0:
                self.unsetCursor()
        elif handle < 0 and not self._resizing:
            pos = event.pos()
            pos.setX(pos.x() + self.offset())
            for section in self.structure.iterate():
                if pos in self.sectionRect(section):
                    self.updateSections(section.column())
                    break
            self.unsetCursor()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self._resizing = False
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.translate(.5, .5)
        height = self.height()
        rowHeight = height / self.structure.subLevels()
        qp.translate(-self.horizontalOffset(), 0)
        column = 0
        for parent in self.structure.children():
            self.paintSubSection(qp, parent, 0, rowHeight)
            column += 1


class CustomHeaderTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    structure = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        customHeader = AdvancedHeader(self)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(customHeader)
        customHeader.setSectionsClickable(True)
        customHeader.setHighlightSections(True)

        self.cornerHeader = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.cornerHeader.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.cornerHeader.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid black;')
        self.cornerHeader.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.verticalHeader().setMinimumWidth(
            self.cornerHeader.minimumSizeHint().width() + self.fontMetrics().width(' '))
        self._cornerButton = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)

        self.setStructure(kwargs.get('structure') or Section('ROOT', isRoot=True))

        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selectionModelSelChanged)

    def setStructure(self, structure):
        if structure == self.structure:
            return
        self.structure = structure
        if not structure:
            super().setColumnCount(0)
            self.cornerHeader.setText('')
        else:
            super().setColumnCount(structure.columnCount())
            self.cornerHeader.setText(structure.label)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStructure(structure)
        self.updateGeometries()

    def selectionModelSelChanged(self):
        # update the corner widget
        selected = len(self.selectionModel().selectedIndexes())
        count = self.model().rowCount() * self.model().columnCount()
        font = self.cornerHeader.font()
        font.setBold(selected == count)
        self.cornerHeader.setFont(font)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super().updateGeometries()
        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
        if not vHeader.isVisible():
            return
        style = self.verticalHeader().style()
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionHeader()
        opt.initFrom(vHeader)
        margin = style.pixelMetric(style.PM_HeaderMargin, opt, vHeader)
        width = self.cornerHeader.minimumSizeHint().width() + margin * 2
        
        vHeader.setMinimumWidth(width)
        self.cornerHeader.setGeometry(self._cornerButton.geometry())

    def setColumnCount(self, count):
        # ignore column count, as we're using setStructure() instead
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    structure = Structure('UNITE', (
        Section('HOMBRES', (
            Section('Cantidad Total'), 
            Section('C.T sesiones'),
            Section('CT continuadores') 
        )), 
        Section('MUJERES', (
            Section('Cantidad Total'), 
            Section('C.T sesiones'),
            Section('CT continuadores')
        )), 
    ))

    tableWidget = CustomHeaderTableWidget()
    tableWidget.setStructure(structure)

    tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
    tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(
        ['0-3', '4-12', '13-17', '18-29', '30-59', '59 a mas']        
    )

    tableWidget.resize(680, 250)   
    tableWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]